# syntax error near unexpected token `then' in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, syntax-error

below is after set -vx; source ~/.bash_profile per comment by @dash-o

```
mbp:~ pyop$ set -vx ; source ~/.bash_profile
+ source /Users/pyop/.bash_profile
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/pyop/Library/Python/2.7/bin/:/Users/pyop/Library/Python/3.6/bin/:/Users/pyop/miniconda3/bin:/Users/# export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"evault vault.bash.inc' && source '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
-bash: /Users/pyop/.bash_profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
-bash: /Users/pyop/.bash_profile: line 1: `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/pyop/Library/Python/2.7/bin/:/Users/pyop/Library/Python/' export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"evault vault.bash.inc' && source '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
mbp:~ pyop$
```

below is LC_ALL=C cat -v ~/.bash_profile per user comment by @Gordon Davisson

```
mbp:~ pyop$ LC_ALL=C cat -v ~/.bash_profile
LC_ALL=C cat -v ~/.bash_profile
+ LC_ALL=C
+ cat -v /Users/pyop/.bash_profile
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/pyop/Library/Python/2.7/bin/:/Users/pyop/Library/Python/3.6/bin/:/Users/pyop/miniconda3/bin:/Users/pyop/miniconda2/bin:/usr/local/opt/rabbitmq/sbin:$PATH"^M^Mexport CLICOLOR=1^Mexport LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced^M^Mexport PATH=/Users/pyop/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH^M^Malias subl='open -a "Sublime Text"'^Malias bash_profile_reset="source ~/.bash_profile"^Malias vcode='open -a "Visual Studio Code"'^Malias chrome='open -a "Google Chrome"'^Malias intel='open -a "IntelliJ IDEA"'^M^Malias runelixir="iex -S mix run"^M^Mexport PATH="/Users/pyop/terraform:$PATH"^M^Mexport PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"^Mexport GEM_HOME=/Users/pyop/.gem^Mexport PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH"^M^Mexport NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"^M^M. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh^M^M. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash^M^Mexport PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"^M^Mexport WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs^Msource /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh^Mexport PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl-openssl/bin:$PATH"^Meval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/perl5)"^Mif which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi^M^M# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.^M# -f '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' && source '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'^M^M# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.^M# -f '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' && source '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'^M^Mcomplete -C /Users/pyop/terraform/vault vault^M# export GOPATH=/Users/pyop/gocode^M# export GOPATH=$GOPATH^M# export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"^Mmbp:~ pyop$
```

below is after simple source ~/.bash_profile

```
-bash: /Users/pyop/.bash_profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
-bash: /Users/pyop/.bash_profile: line 1: `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/pyop/Library/Python/2.7/bin/:/Users/pyop/Library/Python/3.6/bin/:/Users/pyop/miniconda3/bin# -f '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' && source '/Users/pyop/google-# -f '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' && source '/Users/pyop/g' export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"evault vault
```

above is the readout after source ~/.bash_profile

below is my .bash_profile

I have been using this file with no problem until I installed go and now it has a problem with it.

I have removed and commented out parts of it, but no success.

Any help is appreciated.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/pyop/Library/Python/2.7/bin/:/Users/pyop/Library/Python/3.6/bin/:/Users/pyop/miniconda3/bin:/Users/pyop/miniconda2/bin:/usr/local/opt/rabbitmq/sbin:$PATH"

export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced

export PATH=/Users/pyop/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH

alias subl='open -a "Sublime Text"'
alias bash_profile_reset="source ~/.bash_profile"
alias vcode='open -a "Visual Studio Code"'
alias chrome='open -a "Google Chrome"'
alias intel='open -a "IntelliJ IDEA"'

alias runelixir="iex -S mix run"

export PATH="/Users/pyop/terraform:$PATH"

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export GEM_HOME=/Users/pyop/.gem
export PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh

. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash

export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"

export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl-openssl/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/perl5)"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
# -f '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' && source '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
# -f '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' && source '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'

complete -C /Users/pyop/terraform/vault vault
# export GOPATH=/Users/pyop/gocode
# export GOPATH=$GOPATH
# export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Consider trying the following 'set -vx ; source ~/.bash_proflle`. It will provide line by line detail. Most likely, the problem is with one of the sourced files (asdf.bash, asfd.sh, virtualenvwrapper.sh, ...)

Comment: That error message is weirdly garbled, and only partly matches what's in the file. This makes me wonder if there are some sort of invisible/weird characters in the file messing it up. Try printing it with `LC_ALL=C cat -v ~/.bash_proflle` and see if that shows anything weird.

Comment: Thanks for the help @GordonDavisson . I put what happens with the command you suggested above in a post edit.

Comment: I tried to format your post, please check. Please format code blocks with 4 leading spaces. The `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/pyop/Library/Python/2.7/bin/:/Users/pyop/Library/Python/3.6/bin/:/Users/pyop/miniconda3/bin:/Users/# export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"evault vault.bash.inc' && source '/Users/pyop/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'` this is something strange. Och, in `cat -v` it's visible - `^M` this is only `\r`. So you have a file with CR line breaks.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I formated the leading for spaces that I think you're talking about. I don't know how to remove the ^M in my .bash_profile if that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `cat -v` suggest that your file is formatted using only carriage return character as the line endings. This is something unusual. More information about line endings can be found on [wiki newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). It would be wise to check the encoding and settings of the editor you used to create and/or edit the file. You may also try inspect the file in a hex editor or for example with `hexdump -C`.

Bash parses files expecting only the line feed character to be used as the line ending. Because bash finds none line feed characters, he parses the whole file as a single line.

To replace all carriage return characters to line feed characters, you can use `tr`:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < ~/.bash_profile > tempfile
mv tempfile ~/.bash_profile
```

Or for example with gnu sed:

```
sed -i -e 's/\r/\n/g' ~/.bash_profile
```

It may be possible your file is formatted using dos line endings - ie. both carriage return and line feed characters are used to represent a line ending - but you copied the output of `cat -v` to the question improperly. Use `dos2unix` utility or something like `sed -i -e 's/\r//' ~/.bash_profile` to convert the sequence of carriage return + line feed characters into a single line feed.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you @KamilCuk :) The .bash_profile worked after your tr and mv commands.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the the posted bash script. Most likely, this is a result of referencing other bash scripts: asdf.bash, asdf.sh, virtualenvwrapper.sh, ...

Executing "set -vx ; source ~/.bash_profile" should help narrow the problem

Comment: If the culprit is one of the sourced script, how come that the error message refers to line 1 of .bash_profile?

Comment: Depending on the severity of the error, bash may not be able to report the correct location of the problem. Using `-vx` is a quick and economic way to identify the source line of the problem. If I had to make a guess, it would bet that the problem is with dynamic code (`eval`, or similar).

Comment: I agree that `-vx` is the way to research the issue; I just wondered how the line number and file reference can be THAT wrong. At least it should point to the line of the offending `source` statement. For this kind of error message, I would have guessed that the OP modified the file while bash was still sourcing it, but from how he describes the problem, this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: I'm sure that once we identify the problem, it will make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help @dash-o . I put the response from the command you suggested in an edit to my original post above.